# Creating generic DbSets based on entity types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, code-first, dbset

In EF code first using following peace of code, I could create non-generic `DbSets` based on each entity type:

```
foreach (var entry in _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>())
{
    BaseEntity entity = entry.Entity;
    Type type = entity.GetType();
    var set = _dbContext.Set(type);
}
```

Is there any way to create them as Generic `DbSet`s?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. You could call the correct generic overload of `Set<>` using reflection, if you really needed to get the generic `DbSet`. Beyond that, in order to call the generic methods you need to know the correct generic type parameters *at compile time*. Reflection aside, any time you end up using `Type` objects at runtime you lose the ability to use generic types.